# default constructor c++ format

Tags: c++, constructor

I need to create a program that has 3 sets and 3 gets as well as a constructor. however, when I created the default constructor, it gave me an error that states there need to be a ')' before ',' in line

```
#include <string>

class Vehicle
{
public:
    Vehicle(std::string vehicleType, int numberOfDoors, int maxSpeed)
         : type{vehicleType}, number{numberOfDoors}, speed{maxSpeed}{}
    void setType(std::string vehicleType) {
                 type = vehicleType;}
    void setNumber(int numberOfDoors){
                  number = numberOfDoors;}
    void setSpeed(int maxSpeed) {
                 speed = maxSpeed;}

    Vehicle(string, int, int);
    ~Vehicle();
    Vehicle();
    std::string getType() const {return type;}
    int getNumber() const {return number;}
    int getSpeed() const {return speed;}

private:
    std::string type;
    int number;
    int speed;
};
```

Can someone tell me what is wrong?

Comment: `Vehicle(string, int, int);` - it should be `std::string`. `string` is not name of the type here.

Comment: Why are you declaring the same constructor twice? `Vehicle(std::string vehicleType, int numberOfDoors, int maxSpeed)` and `Vehicle(string, int, int)`.

Comment: @iosdude
If i left it alone, it would tell me unidentifed reference to vehicle:vehicle which means there's no default constructor

Comment: as @iosdud mention you are declaring parameterized constructor twice. Also your default constructor is not defined, as everything is inline, I expect this is not defined in cpp file. Or simply use `Vehicle() = default;` and `~Vehicle() = default;` c++11 feature.

Comment: @swapnil

Thank you so much. I just needed to figure out a way to declare the vehicle default and read somewhere that Vehicle(string, int, int) was the right way to do it

Comment: @xx123 In order for `Vehicle::Vehicle` to be defined it needs to have a body, otherwise it's just a declaration, not definition. You can do that in your .cpp file or inline in the class declaration (in header).

Answer (score 1):

You have already defined three argument constructor at the beginning of your class, where you are using member initializer list to initialize member variables of your class `Vehicle`. Hence you do not need to declare it again below:

```
Vehicle(string, int, int);
```

If you remove this line, you code will compile. See [here](http://ideone.com/bSGPm6)

When you instantiate your class, you will need to provide three arguments, one `string` and two `int`s

Further, if you like to have a default constructor, you can add the following line to your class.

```
Vehicle():type(), number(0), speed(0){}
```

Then you should be able to instantiate your `Vehicle` class without any arguments and user Setter functions to set values to member variables of such an object.

Also either remove the not defined destructor OR define the destructor maybe this way:

```
~Vehicle(){ type.clear();}
```

See [here](http://ideone.com/lUrLYS)

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `Vehicle(string, int, int);` as it has already been defined. (check your first constructor)

Comment: If i remove the Vehicle(string, int, int); 
then it tells me I need a default constructor. It gives me a unidentifed reference to "Vehicle::Vehicle"

Comment: You could remove `Vehicle();` and `~Vehicle();` 
or do as @swapnil suggested - `Vehicle() = default;` and `~Vehicle() = default;` if on C++11.